# Firebase emulator --inspect-functions throws unsupported warning

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Somehow i managed to break something with my firebase emulator. It already worked in the past and i don´t know why its no longer working.

When calling

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
```

Everythings starts up as expected, but i get the warning

```
--inspect-functions only supported for Node.js runtimes.
```

When trying to attach the debugger in VS Code its visible in the CALL STACK for ~5 seconds an then disappears.
Also in the terminal i don´t get the "Debugger attached" message when starting.

Here is my launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Debug",
      "restart": true,
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
```

}

Does anyone have a idea why its not working?

Comment: As per the discussion fro this [githud thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4166), Issue must be with `firebase-tools` version. Try downgrading the version.

Comment: Thanks so much! Removed firebase-tools and reinstalled the older version (from v11.22.0 to v11.21.0). It works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the discussion from this [githud thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/416)  , Issue must be with `firebase-tools` version.  Downgrading to an older version (i.e `v11.21.0`) of `firebase-tools` will solve the issue.

Comment: There is also an issue filed now.  Give it a thumbs up to get attention.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5509#issuecomment-1428461711